# Get time in 24 hrs format and hold it in any variable using Javascript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating a time slot in Javascript. Please no jQuery. If you put the first time and last time, then it will make a lists of interval and after 12 number, it will change to am to pm. Suppose, if your start time is 11 and end time is 19, then it will make a  slot like like this,

```
    11AM-12PM
    12PM-1PM
    1PM-2PM
    2pm-3pm
    3pm-4pm
    4pm-5pm
    5pm-6pm
    6pm-7pm
```

But, problem is I am taking it as simple integer and giving for loop. I want hold the 24 hrs format of it, like for

```
    1PM-2PM
```

it should take this value in any variable which will send to server

```
    13:00:00 - 14:00:00
```

Here is my JS code.

```js
getTimeValues: function() {
                        console.log('here i am');
                        var timeValues = this.timeValues;
                        var minTime = 11; //vary this to change the first 
                        var maxTime = 19; //vary this to chage the
                        var string;
                        for (var i = minTime; i < maxTime; i++) {
                                if(i<12) {
                                        lowersuffix = 'AM';
                                        startRange = i;
                                        }
                                        else if(i===12){
                                                lowersuffix = 'PM';
                                                startRange = i;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                                lowersuffix = 'PM';
                                                startRange = i - 12;
                                        }
                                if((i+1)<12) {
                                        uppersuffix = 'AM';
                                        endRange = (i+1);
                                        }
                                        else if((i+1)===12){
                                                uppersuffix = 'PM';
                                                endRange = (i+1);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                                uppersuffix = 'PM';
                                                endRange = (i+1) - 12;
                                        }
                                string = startRange + lowersuffix + '-' + endRange + uppersuffix;
                                console.log(string);
                                timeValues.push(string);
                        };
                },
```

Comment: Have you considered using momentjs? It has built in tokens for formatting http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: why do you format with am/pm if you want 24hrs format?

Comment: It would be much better if you refactored your code to be a function declaration.

Comment: @Michael, I think he just copied somewhere the code and now is asking for help to change it

Comment: Nope, it should show in front-end as 12 hrs format. But I am sending data to server as 24 hrs format. So, I need a variable where I can store the 24 hrs format.

Comment: Post detailed the parameters passed to the function and what you espect as a result, because noone seems to understand!

Comment: then you are misleading us with the title and the text of the question, from your comment I understand that you need a transform function from a format to another, as it was said, did you considered using momentjs?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. I know about momentjs. But, I want to do it without using any library, for my learning purpose.

Comment: create object with `start` and `end` dates. Use angular date filter to display and send whatever you need to server using the object. Stop fiddlling around with a bunch of strings

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
 for (var i = minTime; i < maxTime; i++) {
      string = i + ':00:00 - ' + (i+1) + ':00:00';
      console.log(string);
      timeValues.push(string);
 };
```

Comment: Yeah. But it should show in front-end as 1PM to 2 PM. But I am sending data to server as 24 hrs format.

Comment: hmm I don't really have a clue what you are trying to do. Do you want to display am/pm or 24Hrs format? What format you send to server was never part of the question.

Comment: I am showing 1pm-2pm. This is fine. But I want to hold the value of it in 24 hrs in any variable somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're after a simple function to convert time in am/pm format to 24hr format. The following should do the job, hopefully the comments are sufficient. If not, ask.

```js
/*  @param {string} time - time string in hh:mm:ss am/pm format
**                       - missing time parts are treated as 0
**  @returns {string} time in 24hr format: hh:mm:ss
**/
function to24hrTime(time) {

    // Get the digits from the string
    var b = time.match(/\d+/g);

    // Test whether it's am or pm, default to am
    var pm = /pm$/i.test(time);
    var h, m, s;

    // If no digits were found, return undefined
    if (!b) return;

    // Otherwise, convert the hours part to 24hr and two digits
    h = ('0' + ((pm? 12:0) + (b[0]%12))).slice(-2);

    // Convert minutes part to two digits or 00 if missing
    m = ('0' + (b[1] || 0)).slice(-2);

    // Convert seconds part to two digits or 00 if missing
    s = ('0' + (b[2] || 0)).slice(-2);

    // Return formatted string
    return h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}

document.write(
  to24hrTime('3:15pm') + '<br>' +
  to24hrTime('3:15am') + '<br>' +
  to24hrTime('11am') + '<br>' +
  to24hrTime('11pm') + '<br>' +
  to24hrTime('12AM') + '<br>' +
  to24hrTime('12PM') + '<br>' +
  to24hrTime('11 pm') + '<br>' +
  to24hrTime('12 AM') + '<br>' +
  to24hrTime('12 PM')
);
```

Comment: I am using ng-repeat in html. Please check this plunker code. I want to send back server of this 12 hrs format to 24hrs format. But, from front-end it should show 12 hrs format. http://plnkr.co/edit/heFVMH20QwzDFIcLcQTi?p=preview After selecting date, it will show time slots.

Comment: In HTML, I am taking, time in timeValues. So, if I change the time to 24 hrs, so it will go to server as 24 hrs but front-end view will be changed too.

Comment: The above shows how to convert 12 hr time to 24 hour time, so you display 12 hr, convert to 24 hr, then send to the server. It is intended to be an example, you should adapt it to your circumstance.

Comment: Hi, I have solved it by using your code. But, if I select 1PM-2PM, then in UTC format it is showing 13:02:00 . That is because of the slot. If I just want to take first one in UTC then any suggestion? Like, if you select 1PM-2PM, then in UTC it will show only 13:00:00, that is first one.

Comment: Hi, it is not working incase of AM. It is converting to 24 hrs format AM too. Suppose, incase of 11 AM, it should show 11:00:00

Comment: please look at it once. @robg

Comment: @cyberoy—I have added more examples, "11am" and "11 am" and "11AM" and "11 AM" all become 11:00:00.