# Convert Time string to UTC time format while sending to server by using Javascript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have a calendar which contains date slots and a date slots. I am using AngularJS. After clicking on date, it will show the time slots in 12 hrs format. It will show the interval of times. Suppose, there are options like, 11AM-12PM, 12PM-1PM etc. After selecting any of time slot, it is going back to server. I want to send it back to server in UTC format. But, in front-end it should always show 12 hrs format. I need a variable, where I can store the converted value of 12 hrs to UTC and send it back to server. I have added the plunker below. Check my service JS code for times.
Suppose, if I select 12PM-1PM then at the time of sending this data to server, it should go as 12:00:00-13:00:00
Please check my time generating JS code. Full plunker is added below.

```js
getTimeValues: function() {
        console.log('here i am');
        var timeValues = this.timeValues;
        var minTime = 11; //vary this to change the first 
        var maxTime = 19; //vary this to chage the last 
        var string;
        for (var i = minTime; i < maxTime; i++) {
            if(i<12) {
                        lowersuffix = 'AM';
                        startRange = i;
                        }
                        else if(i===12){
                                lowersuffix = 'PM';
                                startRange = i;
                        }
                        else {
                                lowersuffix = 'PM';
                                startRange = i - 12;
                        }
                if((i+1)<12) {
                        uppersuffix = 'AM';
                        endRange = (i+1);
                        }
                        else if((i+1)===12){
                                uppersuffix = 'PM';
                                endRange = (i+1);
                        }
                        else {
                                uppersuffix = 'PM';
                                endRange = (i+1) - 12;
                        }
                string = startRange + lowersuffix + '-' + endRange + uppersuffix;
                console.log(string);
                timeValues.push(string);
        };
},
```

Full plunker link :- http://plnkr.co/edit/heFVMH20QwzDFIcLcQTi?p=preview

Comment: don't do this.  Use a well tested and maintained library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Comment: I want to do without using any library. It's almost ready, now I don't want to go back.

Comment: this is unmaintainable even if you can get it to output what you want.  It doesn't take into account different time zones, or daylight savings, or any normal date calculations.  Simply put, don't write something like this unless you ***really*** have no other alternative, and then, only write something like this when you have the skill to handle all the edge cases.

Comment: what do you do when the start time is 11pm and the end time is 1am the next day, for example?

Comment: Yeah. For now, I am considering that one day only.

Comment: just pretending an edge case doesn't exist because you don't want to deal with it in your code isn't the right way to solve anything, especially when there is an alternative.  Seeing as angular itself is a library, I'm not sure why you are so against using another library that does exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am not sure that moment.js will give me exact same design or not. Bootstrap default calendar is same, but it is not good by design and not responsive too.

Comment: I was saying about angular-bootstrap-calendar, A port of the bootstrap calendar widget to AngularJS.

Comment: moment.js (if you took the time to research it) is a lightweight library for doing time *calculations*.  It does no rendering, so comparing it to some widget that does rendering isn't an accurate comparison.  Either way, I still believe what you have written is an unmaintainable piece of code.

Comment: A date library won't help much. Converting "7PM" to "19:00:00" is trivial Is "12PM-1PM " to be converted to 12:00 to 13:00 on the current date in the host time zone, then converted to UTC (so if the host is, say, UTC+05:30 then 06:30 to 07:30 UTC)? If you [*abandon questions*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345320/get-time-in-24-hrs-format-and-hold-it-in-any-variable-using-javascript-angularjs/33346437#33346437), don't expect much help.

Comment: @Claies—how is it "unmaintainable"? Many libraries like Moment.js fall into disrepair (what is the average life of a jQuery plugin?), which creates a far greater issue for those who use it than having to repair a simple function like the OP.